# total distance around circle by car

Tags: geometry

let us consider following problem:

A car goes around a circle of radius of $14km$ in the first round it travels with a speed of $11km/hr$ in subsequent rounds its speed increases by $11km/hr$ in each round. how much time does the car take to cover a dist of $440km$

distance around circle  or circumference is $28*
\pi=87.92$,so he needs   $440/87.92=5.0045495905368516833484986351228$,so around $5-6$  circular movement,if  his speed at the begining is  $11$,then first circular round we would take  $7.9927272727272727272727272727273$  or $8$ hour,so  then it's speed is  increased by $11$,so becames $22$,for this it would be $87.92/22=3.9963636363636363636363636363636$ or $4$ hour,for the third it would be    $2$,for the  $4$ it would be $1.something$ and for the $5$ also $1.something$,so it total something between  $12$ and $13$,is it correct approaches?

Comment: Really, we don't need that many digits. We really really really don't.

Comment: i wanted to maximize approxiamtion

Comment: You can't maximize approximation, that is the nature of approximation :)

Comment: nice joke,nice sentences  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the perimeter is $=2\cdot\pi\cdot14\approx 2\cdot\frac{22}7\cdot14=88$ KM

So, the car needs to circumambulate $\approx\frac{440}{88}=5$ times

So, the time taken will be $$\approx\sum_{0\le r\le 4}\frac{88}{11+r\cdot11}\text{ hours }$$

Comment: the same right what i have posted

Comment: @giorgi, apart from approximation hinted by the value of the radius which is divisible by $7$

Comment: so my approaches is correct,just only approximation

Answer (score 0):

The approximation is actually making your calculation lengthy and prone to errors of rounding off, instead work in fractions till the end i.e

- Distance in 1st round/ Circumference of circle = 2 x π x r = 2 x 14 x 22/7 = 88 km
- Speed = 11 km/hr
- Time = Distance/Speed = 88/11 = 8 hrs (this is for 1st round when speed is 11km/hr)
- Total distance to cover = 440 km
- Time taken to complete 440 kms = (Circumference of Circle/Speed in 1st round) + (Circumference of Circle/Speed in 2nd round) + (Circumference of Circle/Speed in 3rd round) + (Circumference of Circle/Speed in 4th round) + (Circumference of Circle/Speed in 5th round)
- 88/11 + 88/22 + 88/33 + 88/44 + 88/55 =>  274/15 hrs or 18.26 hrs